# csv - how do I get the value of a row in a certain line using python and pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas

My csv looks like this:

```
name;        street;         number;
------------------------------------
Jimmy;       Nice Street 24; 24;
Carl;        Great Street;   128;
Tim;         Long Street 5;   - ;
...
```

I read that csv with panda like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'export.csv')
x = data[['name', 'street', 'number']]
```

As you can see the users did not input their adress correctly in line 1 and 2.

So what I want to do is check each street name for a name and if
there is already a number in it. If there is, erase the number from the `street` row and put it in the `number` row if there isn't one yet.
All lines should look like line 2 later.

I am new to python and pandas and can't figure out the smoothest way to do this. Any input is much appreaciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider removing the trailing separators in a source csv. But it is not necessary.

This code will do the magic:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


def check_street_no(row):
    number_match = re.search(r'\d+$', row['street'])
    if number_match is not None:
        row['number'] = number_match.group()
        row['street'] = re.sub(r' *\d+$', '', row['street'])
    return row

data = pd.read_csv(r'streets.csv', sep=';', skiprows=[1], skipinitialspace=True)
data = data.apply(check_street_no, axis=1)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
    name        street number
0  Jimmy   Nice Street     24
1   Carl  Great Street    128
2    Tim   Long Street      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for replace `NaN`s to original values, for reorder columns use [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'export.csv', sep=';', skiprows=[1], skipinitialspace=True)

#if necessary remove columns full of NaNs
df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
df1 = df['street'].str.extract('(?P<street>[a-zA-z\s]+) (?P<number>\d+)', expand=True)
print (df1)
        street number
0  Nice Street     24
1          NaN    NaN
2  Long Street      5

df = df1.combine_first(df).reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
    name        street number
0  Jimmy   Nice Street     24
1   Carl  Great Street    128
2    Tim   Long Street      5
```